# Why does a multi-function line of code not produce an error and simply halt execution?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, error-handling

I understand the below line of code is horrible coding, but my question is why does this type of code not produce a console error, and simply halt execution instead?

Example:

Assuming that there is a session storage item called `mySessionItem`, and its value is JSON with the property `myObjectProperty` in it, the following code when executed will work when the session storage item is set and has valid JSON.

```
let myVar = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("mySessionItem"))["myObjectProperty"] === "myValue" ? false : true;
```

However if the session storage is not set, or is set to invalid JSON, or valid JSON but is missing the property `myProperty`, it errors and halts execution.

This is normal behavior and something I would expect from such poor code. However this does not produce a console error, making it extremely difficult to track down.

Is there a reason that this does not result in a console error, is there any way I can force it to generate one programatically, and is there any easy way to track down issues like this?

I work on a large team with members of varying levels of coding ability, and as things like this enter the code-base I'd like to find better ways of tracking them since they can be quite elusive in a large application and wreak havoc everywhere.

For reference our team is using Angular 2 implemented via the Angular CLI using TypeScript.  I'm not sure if one of these things plays a role in the bad code generating an error not so I wanted to make sure that I emphasized what tools we were using.

Comment: I get an error in the console: `VM140:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'myObjectProperty' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:64`

Comment: So perhaps it is something to do with it being in Angular 2, TypeScript etc?

Comment: Not a solution, but what if you put a `try ... catch` around it, and console log the error, what happens?

Comment: @StephenRios do you by chance have this code within an observable sequence? If so, console log the error in the error callback of the subscribe function. The rxjs .map() method will catch the error and throw it to the error callback (just like try catch)

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line. When it hits it, step over it. It will not proceed to the next line, but will likely go into some Angular code that swallows the exception.

Comment: You are perfectly correct Mike.  Can you put that in an answer that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like create a class in Typescript for the session object then try to access the property since that class will always have that property.

```
> let myVar: boolean = new Session(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("mySessionItem"))).myObjectProperty === "myValue" ? false : true;
```

This uses some of the type-safety features of Typescript and you get to control what happens to the session Object in the constructor if lets say the property is not set or missing.

```
constructor(options: { myObjectProperty?: string } = {}){
   this.myPropertyObject = options.myPropertyObject || '';
}
```

Comment: This would definitely be one way of keeping this one-liner safe. I appreciate the input on ways to make it safer.